# Unable to find files in dbfs after creating a parquet file in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, parquet, delta-lake

I created a parquet file and this code was executed successfully. However, in the same path "/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/" there were subfolders lvl2_1 and lvl2_2 which had "delta" files. Upon attempting to access those tables, I get the error "AnalysisException: Delta table "/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/lvl2_1" doesn't exist.
Checking the files using `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/lvl2_1")` shows 3 files viz. _SUCCESS, _delta_log, *committed*.
I have checked the path and have accessed the table before many times, but now I cannot access this delta file due to above error.
The only action that has been performed related to this folder was the creation of parquet file. I am not sure what caused the error.
I would appreciate any information on identifying the issue here, so that it is not repeated. Please let me know in case any other information is required.

I created a parquet file using the following command:

```
output_path = "/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/"
df\
.write\
.mode("overwrite")\
.format("parquet")\
.save(output_path)
```

This code was executed successfully.
However, in the path "/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/" there were subfolders lvl2_1 and lvl2_2 which had "delta" files. Upon attempting to access those tables, I get the error "AnalysisException: Delta table "/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/lvl2_1" doesn't exist.
Checking the files using `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/lvl2_1")` shows 3 files viz. _SUCCESS, _delta_log, *committed*.
I have checked the path and have accessed the table before many times, but now I cannot access this delta file due to above error.
The only action that has been performed related to this folder was the creation of parquet file.
My expectation was to save parquet file in the output_path without deleting/corrupting anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the files present inside `lvl2_1` are deleted, and the deletion is triggered due to writing `parquet` files in `Overwrite` mode. Even though you have a `_delta_log` file, it still gives you an error.

Whenever you try to write data to `parquet`, you need to specify a path that is an empty directory, or the `Overwrite` option should be given.

In your case, since you are overwriting the files, all underlying parquet files have been deleted. If you see the committed file in the delta table, it shows the files removed.

[image]

My suggestion is to save data in parquet and delta format in different directories, instead of saving it in a single directory like `lvl2_par`.

```py
output_path = "/mnt/dev/lvl1/lvl2/lvl2_par/"
df\
.write\
.mode("overwrite")\
.format("parquet")\
.save(output_path)
```

This will never give you an error or create conflicts between parquet and delta unless you provide a parent directory with the overwriting option.